# HTML select option is undefined in PHP (JS can read its value) - AJAX form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, select

I'm trying to make a "sort" button. When someone chooses something from a list (HTML select) it will sort items from my database on my HTML page.

```
// head
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#sort_form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: 'php/file-php.php',
                data: new FormData(this),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function () {
                    alert($("#sort").val());
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
// HTML
<?php require "php/file-php.php"; ?>

<form method="POST" id="sort_form" action="php/file-php.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

  <input type="submit" id="sort_btn" value="Sort">
                    
  <select name="sort" id="sort">          
    <optgroup label="alphabetically">
      <option value="alphabet_p"> 
      A-Z
      </option>

      <option value="alphabet_rev_p">
      Z-A
      </option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="in whole portion">
      <option value="kcal_low_a">
      Kcal (to highest)
      </option>

      <option value="kcal_high_a">
      Kcal (to lowest)
      </option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

</form>
<?php 
  recipe_list_dishes();
?>
```

```
// PHP (php/file-php.php)
<?php
    function recipe_list_dishes() {
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cookbook");
        $sort = $_POST["sort"];
        $dish_type = "'dishes'";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE type = $dish_type ORDER BY name";
        
        $kcal_query = "(fat * 9 + carbohydrates * 4 + fiber * 2 + protein * 4)";
        $carbohydrates = "carbohydrates / 10";
        $wpts_query = "(fat * 9 + protein * 4) / 100";

        switch ($sort) {
            case "alphabet_p":
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE type = $dish_type ORDER BY name";
            break;
                
            case "alphabet_rev_p":
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE type = $dish_type ORDER BY name DESC";
            break;
   
            case "kcal_low_a":
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE type = $dish_type ORDER BY $kcal_query";
            break;
            
            case "kcal_high_a":
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE type = $dish_type ORDER BY $kcal_query DESC";
            break;
        }

        $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $recipename = $row['name'];
            $fat = (int)$row['fat'];
            $carbohydrates = (int)$row['carbohydrates'];
            $fiber = (int)$row['fiber'];
            $protein = (int)$row['protein'];
            $weight = (int)$row['weight'];
            $portion = (int)$row['portion'];
            
            $kcal = ($fat * 9) + ($carbohydrates * 4) + ($fiber * 2) + ($protein * 4);
            $cp = $carbohydrates / 10; // Carbohydrate portion = 10g carbs
            $wpts = ($fat * 9 + $protein * 4) / 100; // Warsaw Pump Therapy School = (fat kcal + protein kcal) / 100
            
            echo "<a href='".$recipename."'>".$recipename."</a>";
            echo "Whole:<br>";
            echo round($kcal, 1)." kcal<br>";
            echo round($cp, 1)." WW<br>";
            echo round($wpts, 1)." WBT<br>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<img src='uploads/".$row['image']."' class='imageaaa'>";
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

Note: there is more code, this is just a shortened version.
When I'm trying to display elements from my database in my HTML file, there is an error

```
Warning
: Undefined array key "sort" in
C:\xampp\htdocs\php\file-php.php
on line
5 (line 5 = $sort = $_POST["sort"];)
```

I checked it in js with `$("#sort").val();` and it seems to work correctly.
It had worked before I used AJAX, but I'm forced to do it this way (I don't want the page to be reloaded after the button submit).
Also, the form isn't sent (items are not being sorted).
How can I fix it?

Edit with new code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
            
        $('#sort_form').on('submit', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: 'php/file-php.php',
                data: new FormData(this),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function () {
                    alert($("#sort").val());
                },
                error: function () {
 
                }
            });

        });
            
    });
</script>
```

```
HTML
<form method="POST" id="sort_form" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

  <input type="submit" id="sort_btn" value="Sort">
                    
  <select name="sort" id="sort">          
    <optgroup label="alphabetically">
      <option value="alphabet_p"> 
      A-Z
      </option>

      <option value="alphabet_rev_p">
      Z-A
      </option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="in whole portion">
      <option value="kcal_low_a">
      Kcal (to highest)
      </option>

      <option value="kcal_high_a">
      Kcal (to lowest)
      </option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

</form>
<?php require "php/display.php" ?> // it displays nothing without it
<?PHP 
  recipe_list_dishes();
?>
                    
<?PHP 
  recipe_list_desserts();
?>
                 
<?PHP 
  recipe_list_snacks();
?>
```

```
//php (php/file-php.php)
<?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cookbook");
        $sort = $_POST["sort"];
        $dish_type = "'dania'";

        $kcal_query = "(fat * 9 + carbohydrates * 4 + fiber * 2 + protein * 4)";
        $carbohydrates = "carbohydrates / 10";
        $wpts_query = "(fat * 9 + protein * 4) / 100";

        switch ($sort) {
            case "alphabet_p":
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE type = $dish_type ORDER BY name";
            break;
                
            case "alphabet_rev_p":
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE type = $dish_type ORDER BY name DESC";
            break;
 
            case "kcal_low_a":
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE type = $dish_type ORDER BY $kcal_query";
            break;
            
            case "kcal_high_a":
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE type = $dish_type ORDER BY $kcal_query DESC";
            break;
        }

echo $sort." hello";
       
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

```
// PHP (php/display.php)
<?php
require "php/file-php.php"; 
    function recipe_list_dishes() {
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cookbook");
        $dish_type = "'dishes'";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE type = $dish_type ORDER BY name";

        $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $recipename = $row['name'];
            $fat = (int)$row['fat'];
            $carbohydrates = (int)$row['carbohydrates'];
            $fiber = (int)$row['fiber'];
            $protein = (int)$row['protein'];
            $weight = (int)$row['weight'];
            $portion = (int)$row['portion'];
            
            $kcal = ($fat * 9) + ($carbohydrates * 4) + ($fiber * 2) + ($protein * 4);
            $cp = $carbohydrates / 10; // Carbohydrate portion = 10g carbs
            $wpts = ($fat * 9 + $protein * 4) / 100; // Warsaw Pump Therapy School = (fat kcal + protein kcal) / 100
            
            echo "<a href='".$recipename."'>".$recipename."</a>";
            echo "Whole:<br>";
            echo round($kcal, 1)." kcal<br>";
            echo round($cp, 1)." WW<br>";
            echo round($wpts, 1)." WBT<br>";
            echo "<img src='uploads/".$row['image']."' class='imageaaa'>";

        }
        mysqli_close($con);
    }

?>
```

There can be some mistakes because I have to change some names to English. As you can see I have more functions to display the data, they have a different `$dish_type` value.

Comment: Note that the file in your error message is `rfilet-php.php` and you posted `file-php.php`

Comment: *"I checked it in js with $("#sort").val();"* - Be sure also to check the actual POST request being made in your browser's debugging tools and see if it contains the data you expect.

Comment: You that second file you have shown - presumably you request that via GET first, to get the initial form shown in the first place? Well if you call `recipe_list_dishes()` then, of course there won't be _any_ POST data.

Comment: @CBroe To be honest, I don't really understand what you mean. I'm a noob in PHP. Could you explain what I should do?

Comment: The first request you make, to get your form shown to begin with, will be a GET request. But you are calling `recipe_list_dishes()` in that very same file already, without even checking whether any POST data exist. You need to check what the request method was first (or check for the existence of the submit button value in $_POST), and only then call that function.

Comment: Or, better yet - separate this into individual files to begin with. If you want to make the request via AJAX not - then there is no reason for the call to `recipe_list_dishes()` to be in that script file that generates the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Gathering the data

You have this JS code for submit:

```
    $(function () {
        $('#sort_form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: 'php/file-php.php',
                data: new FormData(this),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function () {
                    alert($("#sort").val());
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Here you instantiate [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), passing `this`, that is, the element whose event is being processed. It would not hurt to use a debugger and check the result of `FormData` instantiation, see whether your sort is indeed loaded. Of course, this should be the case, given the fact that your `select` tag has the `name` of `sort`, but it is not necessarily the case.

## Check the request data

When you test this in the browser, looking for `$("#sort").val()` actually checks whether the element with the `id` of `sort` has a (proper) value. However, if this element has a proper value, that does not mean that it is actually being sent to the server via the request. You only assume that if the value is proper, then it is being sent.

To actually test this, you will need to open the Dev Tools of your browser, navigate to the Network tab and see the requests being sent. When this preparement is done, you can submit your form via AJAX (click on the button) and see a new line in the requests grid of the Network tab of the Dev Tools of your browser. See what is being sent in the payload tab if you have such a tab or wherever your browser shows the request parameters. If you see the `sort` parameter there with proper value, THEN you know that your `sort` value was successfully sent to the server.

## Separate the initial page load from the submit of your form

As it is, your code calls `recipe_list_dishes();` just after your `form` is defined. So, `recipe_list_dishes()` is called **before** you submitted the `form` and at this stage, you do not have anything resembling a `$_POST["sort"]` at the server-side, which gives you the warning you have mentioned in your question.

You will need to avoid calling this function just after your HTML and, instead, make sure that it's properly reached when you actually submit your `form`. So, first your page is loaded, then, you submit your `form`. Your code that runs when the page initially loads assumes that a `sort` was already submitted, which of course does not happen when you load your page, it only happens when you actually submit the `form`.

## Default your sort value

You have this code

```
$sort = $_POST["sort"];
```

which assumes that whenever this code runs, you have a posted `sort`. Don't assume that. Instead, default it to some value, so, if for whatever reason sort is not properly defined, the page and the form would still be operational (for example if you or one of your colleagues mistakenly remove the sort select, or rename it or whatever, then, instead of having errors, the sort would fail gracefully). So, let's use a default if needed:

```
$sort = isset($_POST["sort"]) ? $sort = $_POST["sort"] : "alphabet_p";
```

## SQL injection

Finally, you do not protect your code. You should use parameterized queries to sanitize and protect against [SQL injection](https://www.sonarqube.org/developer-edition/?gads_campaign=Europe-3-Generic&gads_ad_group=Code&gads_keyword=sql%20injection&gclid=Cj0KCQjw_7KXBhCoARIsAPdPTfh9DJxatZijT5Xt7M_Xg_IQr9SckaBKwMm7E_di-GN-Ef5I9YKYhhkaAmXQEALw_wcB#security_vulnerability). I admit that as it stands, your code looks to be safe, but it's only an accident, because the one parameter that you receive is not actually injected into your SQL code, but that could change anytime, so I strongly advise you to look into SQL injection, sanitize your code and, if you will get parameters that are actually injected into your query, if you apply this good practice, then it is unlikely that you would end up with a vulnerability. While, with your current code, which ignores this danger after some evolution can easily become vulnerable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The error disappeared, but I still have some issues. I checked and the "sort" value is sent correctly (thank you for the tip), but there is still no action after I click the submit button. I called  ``` <?php require "php/file-php.php"; ?> ``` just before the  ``` recipe_list_dishes();  ``` function. I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: @Astw41 Since you already checked whether sort was correctly sent, you already know where the Network tab of the Dev Tools is. When you send a request, besides the Payload tab (inside the Network tab), there is another subtab, called Response. I'm interested to know what the response of your request is. You either get a correct response and handling that response badly, or the response is incorrect in the first place. So, the next step is to find out what response is your browser receiving from the server and depending on the response, we will either focus on the browser or the server.

Comment: The response tab is empty. I deleted "e.preventDefault();" line from AJAX function and it worked, but it's not the solution for me, I need this to work without page reload.

Comment: @Astw41 I understand your current issue. Basically, you have a function in the php/file.php.php, but it's never called by that file. And you include the same file into the form that you have. So, you need to perform the following steps to refactor your code:

Comment: @Astw41 1. Remove the `<?php require "php/file-php.php"; ?>` line from your HTML, you do not need this PHP to be evaluated at all, remember, this is the time when the form is loaded, so you do not need to handle any submit events at this stage.

Comment: @Astw41 2. Add to your php/file-php.php file at its very end this logic: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { recipe_list_dishes(); }` (it's ugly here in the comment, please refactor it when you use it). If everything is well, then your form will work now. If not, let me know about the problem. But you are not done in neither case, this is not yet elegant.

Comment: @Astw41 3. Remove the code written at point 2. (I know, you have just implemented it and it might be working, but you will need to do it, trust me). Create a new file that requires php/file-php.php and will do the recipe_list_dishes. The reason for this is to separate request logic from backend app logic. You will thank yourself later if you get used to this now.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, but nothing has changed. Can it even work? I mean changing SQL query without page refresh

Comment: @Astw41 I do not know exactly your situation. If you have problems, then you need to edit your question with your current code so we would be talking about the same thing. Please let me know afterwards here.

Comment: @Astw41 "Can it even work? I mean changing SQL query without page refresh" the precise goal of AJAX is to send requests, get responses without refreshing the page. You will only need to send the request, which seems to be working and when the request is being ended, check the response in the response tab of the Network tab in Dev Tools, because that's the most reliable information source when it comes to request responses.

Comment: @Astw41 it is highly probable that some nuance was done badly. It is of no surprise, this is difficult when you do it for the first time and unluckily, I'm so used to it that I cannot imagine what might have been the most probable problem in this case. So, please edit your question, add some screenshots about the payload and the response, also the url where the request is being sent and the relevant part of the code. We do not expect your page to work properly yet, because it only alerts the sort, so it will not work. We expect the response to be correct.

Comment: @Astw41 once the response is correct, we can also resolve your response handler.

Comment: I edited my post to add my current code.

Comment: @Astw41 looked into it. So, basically you have a logic that assumes a sort to exist and you need the same logic when you load the page and when you get the response of a submit. You have two issues: 1. At page load you do not have a sort and 2. Your Javascript code ignores the response and alerts the sort instead.

Comment: @Astw41 I understand that you need that php/file-php.php even at page load. Then you can use it there of couse, but you did not apply the defaulting I have suggested in my answer.

Comment: @Astw41 This line `$sort = isset($_POST["sort"]) ? $sort = $_POST["sort"] : "alphabet_p";` ensures that you have a valid `$sort` value even if it was not correctly passed to your server. For example, when you load the page, `$_POST["sort"]` is not defined. So, you **need** to check whether it is set and use a default if not. This is the very first thing you need to do from this point onwards and let's have doable, modest expectations. At this point we only expect the page load not to show the error, even though you call the `recipe_list_dishes()` function.

Comment: @Astw41 also, I'm confused about your file structure, as you earlier had this php/file-php.php file, now your edited question refers to php/display.php. Are these the same? Also, you have some function calls here that appear to be undefined, such as `recipe_list_desserts();`. Shall I assume that these are also defined in php/display.php, but you just didn't share it here for the sake of simplicity?

Comment: Yes, I think that there is too much code, so I didn't want to show even more. Other functions like recipe_list_desserts(); look the same, but the $dish_type is different. I thought you wanted me to make another file with recipe_list_xxx() functions (display.php) and leave the switch function in file-php.php. I applied the line with sort (isset) but deleted it later when was experimenting (it's added back now).

Comment: @Astw41 Is it safe to assume that now, upon page load you no longer get an error?

Comment: Yes, there is no error :)

Comment: @Astw41 excellent, then we get to the next step. You said that you do not get anything in the response of the request. I would like to kindly ask you to create a brand new php file which would simply echo out some text, whatever you prefer and change your JS request sending to direct to that new file. Please also tell me whether you see your text in the response of the request. The aim is to test your request sending mechanism and to the prerequisites to your solution.

Comment: If I understand correctly - I created a test.php file with ``` <?php echo "please work :c"; ?> ``` in it. I changed URL in my ajax script to 'php/test.php'. Result: There is no desired text on my page, but it's shown in the network tab.

Comment: @Astw41 that's the exact behavior we wanted to reach. We are almost there. We now want to see a proper response in your network tab. To achieve that, in your new php file remove the dummy content, `require` the file which contains the function you wanted to call and call the function, like `require "<thepathofthefile>"; recipe_list_dishes();`. If you see the response in the Network tab, then your server already operates properly.

Comment: @Astw41 in that case you will need to change your dummy code of `alert($("#sort").val());` in the `success` callback. You will need to pester the parameters, I think you can do it like this: `success: function(response) {$("body").append(response);}`. That will add the response to your page (but, again, I do not know out of hand how this callback is parameterized). If that happens, then the only thing left is to remove the old content. If you wrap a `div` around your content like `<div class="wrapper">...</div>` that you might need to override,...

Comment: @Astw41 ... then your success handler will look like `function(response) {$(".wrapper").html(response);}`

Comment: I've got these errors: ``` Warning: require(php/file-php.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\display.php on line 2

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'php/file-php.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\display.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\php\test.php(2): require() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\display.php on line 2 ```

Comment: @Astw41 no worries about that! I guess you created that new file into the php folder as well and it's on the same location. Maybe `require "file-php.php";` will work. If not, then you will need to look into this in a deeper manner.

Comment: No, I'm just stupid. When you told me to require the PHP file with sorting script in the recipe_list_dishes() function I required "php/file-php.php" instead of "file-php.php". Now I see the data from my database, but still can't sort them.

Comment: @Astw41 is the data sorted in the response of your request in Dev Tools?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: I take that back. I've done some experiments and it now works fine in the "preview" in the dev tools, but still no success on the page

Comment: @Astw41 so basically the client-side sends correct data, the server receives it and processes is correctly, sends it correctly to the browser and the browser does not handle the response correctly. Have you seen my notes about the success handler in earlier comments? Have you created a `div` just after the `form`? It would be great if you had a `<div class="wrapper"></div>` just after the `form` and you would have the php code you have inside that `div`, so you could easily change its content via `$(".wrapper").html("yourhtmlhere")`. In that case you could put your response as parameter.

Comment: I've had some more problems, but I think I finally figured it out. The content after clicking submit button was appearing after the already existing one (it was sorted correctly, it just appeared as another list). In my ajax success function I put: ```$(".bbb").empty(); $(".bbb").prepend(response);``` and it replaces the content instead of adding a new one. I also put ``` <?php require "php/display.php"; ?> ``` in my container for the content, so it is shown after the page is loaded. Thank you for the help! I really appreciate that there are people who help noobs like me :)

Comment: @Astw41 happy to help! The code you have shared in the previous comment removes the content of `(".bbb")` and then prepends the `response`. A simpler way would be `$(".bbb").html(response);`.

Answer (score 0):

In the file-php.php file you need to set an isset condition to get the data posted via ajax on this file.

Remove the function "recipe_list_dishes" and put the code inside the isset() condition.

```
data: new FormData(this),
```

Thus in the file-php.php file you need to start with the condition stated below:

```
if(isset($_POST['sort'])){
   $sort=$_POST['sort'];
   print_r($sort); 
   //to see what exactly are you getting.
   //you must be getting the values : alphabet_p or alphabet_rev_p or kcal_low_a or kcal_high_a
}
```

Another thing that is not according to the standards that I found at the end of your file-php.php is:

```
echo "<a href='".$recipename."'>".$recipename."</a>";
            echo "Whole:<br>";
            echo round($kcal, 1)." kcal<br>";
            echo round($cp, 1)." WW<br>";
            echo round($wpts, 1)." WBT<br>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<img src='uploads/".$row['image']."' class='imageaaa'>";
```

REPLACE IT WITH THE CODE PROVIDED BELOW:

```
$response = "<a href='".$recipename."'>".$recipename."</a>Whole:<be>";
$response .= round($kcal, 1)." kcal<be>";
$response .= round($cp, 1)." WW<be>";
$response .= echo round($wpts, 1)." WBT<be>";
$response .= "<br>";
$response .= "<img src='uploads/".$row['image']."' class='imageaaa'>";
```

outside the while loop you can

```
echo $response;
```

This $response contains some HTML which will be returned to the AJAX success function as a response from the PHP file